# I can't access the window global function in script.js file

Tags: javascript, html, function, global-variables

below is my code for the Window function which is present in a global.js file. so here is my question. i have a project which is a game. in this game i have a global function in a file named global.js which contains a function eventHandler this function is stated global by attaching it to window object. now i am trying to access this function in the script.js file in onload but i am getting an error. I have included all the code below.

```js
window.eventHandler = function (event) {
  console.log("message", event);
  console.log("message on game over", event);
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1) {
    let eventMessage = JSON.stringify(event);
    Android.logEvent(eventMessage);
    console.log("in ANDROID condition");
  }
  if (
    window.webkit &&
    window.webkit.messageHandlers &&
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.toggleMessageHandler
  ) {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.toggleMessageHandler.postMessage({
      message: event,
    });
  }
};
```

below is my script.js file where i am trying to access this eventHandler function.

```js
function fnLoad() {
  function hideClass(name) {
    var myClasses = document.querySelectorAll(name),
      i = 0,
      l = myClasses.length;

    for (i; i < l; i++) {
      myClasses[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  var event = {
    score: 45
  }
  window.eventHandler(event)
}
```

but in the browser i am getting this error.

```
script.js:749 Uncaught ReferenceError: eventHandler is not defined
```

also this is my html file where i have included scripts for script.js and global.js files.

```html
<body id="t" onload="fnLoad()" ontouchmove="event.preventDefault()">
  <script src="../../global.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  
</body>
<!-- <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script> -->

</html>
```

Comment: That's quite a large amount of code. Can you skim that down to a [mre]?

Comment: hi there I have edited the code and made it simpler now you can review it without any problem @Plagiatus

Comment: much better, thank you, but there is still some code that is unrelated to this question (like the `hideClass` function). But either way, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code, it works fine. Make sure your `global.js` script is actually loaded (aka that the path is correct) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Use the Network tab to make sure the two JS files are loading correctly. Odds are you got the URL to one of them wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I tested the same on my local by keeping global.js and script.js on same level.
It worked perfectly. This means there is something wrong with the import you are doing.

```
 <script src="../../global.js"></script>
```

I think it should be like this.

```
 <script src="./../global.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: here's the thing. global.js is in the root directory while script.js is in a directory which is in the root directory. something like this.. monorepo -> global.js -> game-cheetay -> script.js

Comment: or more like this.. monorepo -> global.js..................

Comment: monorepo -> game-cheetay -> script.js